# Java regex for letter in any language

Tags: java, regex

Title not 100% accurate, I've read the related questions and they haven't really helped by case, although coming close.

I want to split a String so that all non-letter characters are a single item, accounting for any combination of characters in any position, be it double/triple spaces at the stard/end, etc.. Examples are much better than any way I can describe:

`String: " Hello, Tim!  "
desired result: {" ", "Hello", ",", " ", "Tim", "!", " ", " "}`

`String: "Hi 123!&*"
desired result: {"Hi", " ", "1", "2", "3", "!", "&", "*"}`

`String: " الْجُمْلَةُ الاسْمِيَّةُ 2"
desired result: {" ", "2", " ", "الْجُمْلَةُ" ,"الاسْمِيَّةُ"}`

The first regex I tried is: `"\\P{L}"` (match non catagory letter)
This does not work for Arabic or other complex scripts (also tried Kannada)

The second attempt: `"\\p{Space}|\\p{Punct}|\\p{Digit}"` (match almost all the characters I want to split at).
This works much better, words in any language seem to group perfectly, but I get undesired results for things like double/tripple spaces, heres an example;

`String: "Hi  "
result: {"Hi", " ", " "} (correct)`

`String: "Hi  Hi"
result: {"Hi", " ", " ", " ", " ", "Hi"} (incorrect, too many spaces)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WHat si the expected input domain?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The strings can be anything, fetched from an Android EditText if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This works for all languages:

```
str.split("(?<=\\P{L})|(?=\\P{L})")
```

It splits using an alternation of a look behind or a look ahead for a non-letter.

---

#### Update:

While the above works for "most" languages, it seems that Kannada script script characters are not considered to be "letters". This workaround regex, which breaks on spaces, numbers (any language) and punctuations works with "non letter" scripts:

```
str.split("(?<=[\\s\\p{N}\\p{Punct}])|(?=[\\s\\p{N}\\p{Punct}])");
```

---

This Arabic example, created using google translate, works:

```
String str = "شكرا  جزيلا";
String[] split = str.split("(?<=\\P{L})|(?=\\P{L})");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

Output:

```
[شكرا,  ,  , جزيلا]
```

Comment: Interesting, please see a little test class I made here: https://ideone.com/Ion4kq. You are correct, it works with your Arabic sample string. The Arabic and Kannada strings I used are just ones I found on Google. I tried a few more Kannada strings by using Google translate and none of them have split successfully.

Comment: @hamham apologies for not recognising Kannada script, however introducing s right-to-left script is a good edge case. Now there's two things going on here. First, there may be something wrong with the way you're creating your Arabic. I [modified your test](https://ideone.com/Abybk3) and my Arabic split OK (copied from google translate). Secondly, according to POSIX regex, Kannada script seems to be not made of letters??? See updated answer and [this demo](https://ideone.com/iJ0FuS).

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian. Maybe I was just lucky to stumble across this issue with Kannada, I only picked Arabic and Kannada because they were the most complex/coolest looking scripts in my keyboard options haha. I think it's safe to say the solution then is to check against everything but letters, rather than letters themselves, as there is probably other scripts with similar issues. I'll leave this question open for a few days to see if anyone has any other ideas, otherwise I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just want to write a function yourself using Character.isLetter(character) rather than trust a regex.  Chances are Java will be as fast or faster if you do it right, and it will be clearer, simpler and most likely less buggy.

Comment: I disagree. Any time you write your own code, rather than use an existing library (eg `String.split()`), there's a good chance you'll have bugs. All you need is the right regex (not that complicated) for `split()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this also does pretty much the same as regex. See https://ideone.com/2MISn2

Comment: Yes, that was my point.  If you have code available and are not trying to take a filter condition as input from your user then you should not use regex--it is the most cryptic solution available (evidenced by the fact that people have to ask questions to do simple things like this).  Google "Now you have two problems" for some interesting discussions on the topic".  Don't get me wrong, regex is FANTASTIC at doing what it is supposed to do though, passing filters into command line functions where you can't just write code--and scripts where maintenance isn't a primary issue...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have at the moment is this;

`"(?<=\\p{Space}|\\p{Punct}|\\p{Digit})|(?=\\p{Space}|\\p{Punct}|\\p{Digit})"`

It is an adaption of Bohemian's answer to look before/ahead matching the majority of characters I would like to split at.

I imagine it will still have problems, Space/Punct/Digit aren't exactly all the non-launguage letters, but it's still much more reliable than `P{L}` in my tests.

I'm still open to better solutions.

Comment: I (independently) reached the same conclusion - see my modified answer.  Note that `\p{digit}` is only Latin numbers 0-9. Use `\p{N}` for any number any language. Note that I didn't check if Kannada digits (if there are any) are "numbers".